# What does "Login shell" do?

Tags: shell, zsh, iterm2

Recently I experience slow terminal launch time, so I looked into it and found an interesting thing. 
I am using iTerm on MacBook. There is an option choosing the default behavior:

[image: Login shell or zsh]

If I chose "Login shell", it will prompt `Last login: Fri Mar 24 17:27:28 on ttys007` (left side below); if I chose "zsh", it won't prompt anything and launch time is very fast (right side below).

[image: difference between login shell and zsh]

The default shell I use is `zsh`, I wonder what's happening inside "login shell" and why it is so slow compared to pure `zsh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Login shell" runs the usual shell (zsh or bash) in *login* mode, in which the shell processes additional configuration files – such as `.zlogin` or `.bash_profile`. Chances are that those files have too many unnecessary commands – try to keep them as lightweight as possible.

You can try running `zsh -l` and comparing it with regular `zsh`. (While `-l` is not a *standard* "login mode" switch, it's pretty common.)

---

(Though IMHO, it is a bit odd for a terminal app to even run shells in "login mode" at all… It sort of defeats the whole idea of being able to configure different startup commands.)

Comment: I think your answer helped me out of my problem. There is one line `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` which after I commented out "login shell" became incredibly fast. Thanks dude

Comment: Yeah, rvm was horribly slow the last time I tried it as well. But in general, anything that defines _functions_ ought to go to the main config file – `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` – not to the "login" one.

Comment: thx for your advice. I cannot remember why it is there